# List View inline edit changes fields not selected for update

Tags: list-view, lightninglistview

We had a report from our users today about unexpected changes to records (custom object) that were being worked on by two users on the same team.  A review of the object field history indicated that both users had completed updates to a particular field minutes apart.  However, the user credited with the second update denied intentionally updating the field in question.

I was able to reproduce the following scenario in a Summer 23 sandbox using two different browsers to isolate the users:

- User A and User B (same Profile) both open the same Custom object List View (*Lightning*)
- User A selects 10 arbitrary records in the list view by clicking on the checkbox on the left of the view
- User A selects **Field AA** on a record in the list view, edits the value, selects Update 10 selected items, clicks Apply and clicks Save.

Pretty standard stuff.

- User B has taken *no action since opening the List View*, i.e., has not refreshed the view and **Field AA** appears unchanged in the list view
- User B selects the same 10 records in the list view by clicking on the checkbox on the left of the view
- User B selects **Field BB** on a record in the list view, edits the value, selects Update 10 selected items, clicks Apply and clicks Save.

Also pretty standard.

What we observe in the Custom Object History related list (field tracking is on for both fields) is

| Date | Field | User | Original Value | New Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6/12/2023 1:00 PM | **Field AA** | User A | Old Value A | New Value A |
| 6/12/2023 1:10 PM | **Field AA** | User B | New Value A | Old Value A |
| 6/12/2023 1:10 PM | **Field BB** | User B | Old Value B | New Value B |

This was not the expected result.  User B does not know or have a way to know that they are about to revert changes made by User A.  User B selected to update exactly one field but it appears as if <strike>the entire record is</strike> *all of the fields in the view are* being updated based on some cached values.

Is there a way to prevent these kinds of unintentional updates?  I feel like I am missing something obvious here.

*EDIT TO ADD : This behavior is not reproducible in Classic list views*

*EDIT TO ADD : Salesforce support acknowledged that this is a Known Issue but when pressed for a Reference ID I was told "it is currently sitting as an internal investigation so I don't have the permission to share that with any external customers." as well as "It is possible that this has existed since list views were implemented in Lightning and we are no longer investing in the current Aura-based iteration of list views. Instead, we are in the process of rebuilding list views on the LWC framework and plan to release next year. So it might be the case that we fix this as part of the LWC list view migration work. Again, this is just conjecture. I'll need my team to confirm."  I am simply astounded.*

Comment: After further clarifying discussions with the Salesforce team the following Known Issue has been created to acknowledge this data integrity problem https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000uWKxRAAW/multiple-users-can-overwrite-list-view-data-when-inline-editing-in-lightning-experience